# Adding product photos in Email a Friend in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, email

I modified the product_share.html and added this

```
<img src="{{var product_image}}“ border="0" />
```

before

> {{var product_name}}

The email contains has the image box but no product image only the Magento watermark.

what do you think I am missing??